# ASP.NET MVC: Caching combobox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, combobox, telerik

Is it possible to cash drop down list?

I'm using a Telerik MVC Window, ComboBox, and the contents of the window (including ComboBox) is being returned with a partial view. Contents of the partial view depends on the list of parameters, but on the every div in this window there is a combo box contents of which is usually unchanged and it contains ~2000 records.

i'm thinking about returning ViewData["ComboContent"] using separate controller with cashing before returning the window itself, but may be there is a better way...

TIA

updated (my controller code):

```
        [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        [OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByParam = "id")] //Some custom param??
        public ActionResult LoadTimeOffset(int id)
        {
            String error;
            IEnumerable<MyModel> model = repo.GetSomeVariableStuff(id, 10, out error); //always varies
            ViewData["ComboList"] = new SelectList(repo.GetComboitems(id), "Key", "Value", -1); //changes only on id

            if (model.Count() > 0)
            {
                return PartialView("Partial", model);
            }

            return Content(error);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cache the data instead of caching the drop-down.

So, instead of putting the SelectList into the ViewData, put the contents for it:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["ComboList"] == null)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Cache["ComboList"] = repo.GetComboitems(id); //use Add instead so that you can specify the cache duration.
}
ViewData["ComboList"] = HttpContext.Current.Cache["ComboList"]; //take from cache.
```

*Note, code is not accurate, but it is an example only.*

Then, in your view, render the combo.

I hope this helps.